# Watson integration with hybrid mobile application

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson, ibm-mobile-services

How to integrate watson conversation in IBM Mobile First Platform (Hybrid mobile apps) ? Need to access the conversation from mobile apps. Share the links if any..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find online examples describing how to use MobileFirst Adapters in order to access Bluemix services.

Review the following:

MobileFirst Platform Foundation Labs - showing how to implement and integrate various features, including Bluemix services: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/labs/

Implementation on an MobileFirst app which accesses the Watson question & answer service: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/04/29/using-http-adapters-to-access-watson-question-and-answer-service-at-ibm-bluemix/

---

In addition, you may choose to use the new Bluemix Developer Console to start creating your next mobile app:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/developer/getting-started/

From here there are Starters like **Watson Conversation** which set you up with a new project and code to download:

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! ll give a try and let u know.